# How to accept a query and return an async task?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, odata, dynamics-crm-2016

I am getting the following exception:

```
Cannot create an EDM model as the action 'Get' on controller 'Accounts' has a return type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult' that does not implement IEnumerable<T>.
```

When attempting to query my endpoint:

```
http://localhost:8267/api/accounts
```

The AccountsController that is doing the work:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions options)
    {
        var query = options.Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var crmEndPoint = @"HTTPS://MYCRMORG.COM/API/DATA/V8.1/";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(crmEndPoint+query);
        object result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

            return Ok(result);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

**What am I doing wrong? How do I simply add the PathAndQuery to my crmEndPoint and return the result?**

Comment: Shouldn't the OData action method use `IQueryable<T>` as return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OData framework provides extra response formatting/querying rules on top of plain Web API.

Using `ODataQueryOptions` parameter **requires** that the action method returns either `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

`ODataQueryOptions` just helps to parse the incoming OData request url making parameters such as `$filter` and `$sort` accessible through properties.

Your code doesn't need this service because all it does is just redirect the request to the `crmEndPoint`. So, instead of using `options.Request` you can access the request object through the `Request` property of the controller and drop the parameter altogether.

Here's the code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var query = Request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var crmEndPoint = @"HTTPS://MYCRMORG.COM/API/DATA/V8.1/";
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(crmEndPoint + query);
    object result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

        return Ok(result);
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```